# C# Parallel.ForEach XslCompiledTransform vs. Saxon 9.7.0.6 HE

Tags: c#, xslt, saxon, parallel.foreach, xslcompiledtransform

I wanted to migrate my XslCompiledTransform to Saxon 9.7.0.6 HE because of XPath 2.0/XSLT 2.0, but it is way slower than .NET.

I tested each version with a default copy ident XSLT and 15.000 xml files:

```
Saxon with Parallel.ForEach: 00:05:02.9013605
XslCompiledTransform with Parallel.ForEach: 00:00:15.6724146

Saxon with foreach: 00:10:09.7763861
XslCompiledTransform with foreach: 00:03:00.3483324
```

I hope I do something wrong, XslCompiledTransform:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(xsl);

XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
readerSettings.XmlResolver = null;

Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
{
    string target = Path.Combine(output, Path.GetFileName(file));
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(file, readerSettings))
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(target, writerSettings))
        xslt.Transform(xr, xw);
});
```

The Saxon Version:

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
docBuilder.DtdValidation = false;
docBuilder.SchemaValidationMode = SchemaValidationMode.None;
docBuilder.WhitespacePolicy = WhitespacePolicy.PreserveAll;
XsltCompiler compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
XsltExecutable executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xsl));

Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
{
    string target = Path.Combine(output, Path.GetFileName(file));
    XsltTransformer transformer = executable.Load();
    XdmNode input = docBuilder.Build(new Uri(file));
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    serializer.SetOutputFile(target);
    transformer.Run(serializer);
});
```

**Update**

I did another test without Visual Studio debugging and it got a lot better:

```
Saxon: 00:00:41.5990128
XslCompiledTransform: 00:00:19.0441044
```

So the main slow down was the debugger itself, but only for Saxon.
Now it only takes twice the time of the .NET version, it is not super great, but I think I can go with that.

Is there anything I can do to make Saxon faster? Maybe play with the code or using EE instead of HE?

Here are some detailed benchmark information, the main performance problem is the DocumentBuilder.Build method. But even the transform itself is more than twice as slow as the .NET version:

**Saxon:**

[image: Saxon]

**.NET:**

[image: .NET]

Comment: Have you tried running the test without Parallel?  If the time difference changes significantly then it may give a hint to the cause.

Comment: Which version of Saxon exactly are you using, just to allow us to understand what your comparison is based on.

Comment: I updated my question and added the times for normal foreach and the Saxon Version.

Comment: Well, in case of performance questions we also need to know whether whether you use the HE or PE or EE version as certainly the commercial versions offer better performance than the open source HE.

Comment: I indeed use the HE version. Maybe someone can test it with the PE version, I did not know that there could be significant performance differences.

Comment: According to http://www.saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-9-7.xml the EE has the most performance related features like byte code generation. You can also request a trial license for the commercial versions to run some tests yourself to see whether it is worth the investment.

Comment: I have to give it a try, I am really happy with the performance of XslCompiledTransform and do not want to slow down too much only for XPath 2.0/XSLT 2.0. I will request the trial and test it again.

Comment: As for discovering the version of Saxon EE you have, run `Transform -?` and I think it outputs the version.

Comment: Thank you! We licensed the Saxon-EE 9.4.0.6 version, so now I have to get the .NET version from Saxonica.

Comment: Are these very small documents? The fact that so much of the time is spent in the Xerces method determineDocVersion() would suggest so. I've come across previous reports that Xerces parser per-document initialization is particularly expensive.

Comment: Since document building is costing you more than transformation, Saxon-EE probably isn't going to help much. It may be worth seeing if document building is faster using the MS parser rather than Xerces. The main problem is that the MS parser doesn't expose attribute type, which means the XPath id() function doesn't work.

Comment: Yes the documents are small, they are S1000D datamodules with 1MB maybe less. Can I use the MS Parser with Saxon? I tried Saxon for the first time with .NET and I am Not familiar with it yet.

Comment: The DocumentBuilder has a build() method that takes an XmlReader as input. I would be interested to know how it compares.

Comment: I did the tests again with XmlReader please see my answer below. Now, I will switch to Saxon, I think the performance loss is worth the use of XPath 2.0 and Xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the test with DocumentBuilder.Build(XmlReader) for Saxon and executed both tests.

```
Console.WriteLine("Saxon:");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        string target = Path.Combine(output, Path.GetFileName(file));
        XsltTransformer transformer = executable.Load();
        XdmNode input = null;
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(file, readerSettings))
            input = docBuilder.Build(xr);
        transformer.InitialContextNode = input;
        Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
        serializer.SetOutputFile(target);
        transformer.Run(serializer);
    });
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + sw.Elapsed);
    RemoveFiles(output);
}
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine("XslCompiledTransform:");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        string target = Path.Combine(output, Path.GetFileName(file));
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(file, readerSettings))
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(target, writerSettings))
            xslt.Transform(xr, xw);
    });
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + sw.Elapsed);
    RemoveFiles(output);
}
```

The results are:

```
Saxon: 210.679ms
XslCompiledTransform: 179.129ms
```

I think this is a great result, the Saxon version only needs 17,61% more time than the XslCompiledTransform version. I can use XPath 2.0 and Xslt 2.0 and only have a performance loss of less than 20%.

Saxon:

[image: Saxon]

XslCompiledTransform:

[image]

Comment: Are the timing results in the text ("Saxon: 179.129ms", "XslCompiledTransform: 210.679ms") unintentionally swapped?

Answer (score 1):

With performance, the devil is always in the detail. This sounds like a scenario that is worth doing some detailed study, so if you can supply us (Saxonica) with everything we need to run it, we'll be happy to take a look.

The first thing that's noticeable from your numbers is that the MS processor gets a much bigger speed-up from parallelizing than Saxon does. That could be because of NamePool contention: we've done a lot to reduce NamePool contention over recent releases, but that's for "typical workloads", and we would need to examine, for example, whether your documents are all using the same vocabulary of names.

The first thing I would want to establish is how much of the cost is document building and how much is transformation. Depending on the answer, subsequent investigation will take a completely different course. (Serialization cost for the result tree could also be a factor, but that would be unusual.)

The .NET version of Saxon is known to be significantly slower than the Java version. Years ago there used to be an overhead of about 30%, but this seems to have increased so it is now 3-5 times slower, and despite considerable efforts, we haven't managed to work out why. We're very dependent here on the IKVMC cross-compiler technology and the OpenJDK library.

Comment: It is unfortunate that MSFT haven't moved on from xsl-1.0 but in their defence they've produced a very fast processor that still to this day sets the high bar for others to compete against.  I've had a long time desire to use xsl-2 (and now xsl-3) in my .net apps but each time I review my options I've concluded cost of the change (not just the cost of product) vs the benefit has not been worthwhile. I've found that I can achieve an ideal balance/compromise using c# extensions with xml.net.  That said, I remain watchful and keen to see the results of any further testing by the OP.

Comment: I am ashamed to admit I tested with the Visual Studio Debugger. So the main performance problem is solved. Can you confirm that 2 times slower is "okay" for the .NET implementation of Saxon?

Comment: I would agree with @PhilBlackburn that it's very hard to compete with the MS product on performance. For most people, doubling developer productivity is well worth doing even if there's a cost in machine performance - machines are cheap, developers are expensive; and there's no doubt that XSLT 2.0 gives you a big productivity boost; also it gives you features like grouping and regexes that help performance. We did some measurements a couple of years ago (reported at XML London) and the comparisons are highly variable depending on the exact workload.